# PHP Regex create something like liquid tags

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to parse something like this

```
{%github user/repo %}
```

Into

```html
<a href="https://github.com/user/repo">Repo</a>
```

This method also should be secure ex: Look below my function.

```php
function parseliquid($string)
{
    $randhashtoreplace = md5(rand(0, 9999));
    $regexp = '/\{%github (.*?)%\}/';
    $str = preg_replace($regexp, $randhashtoreplace, $string);

    preg_match($regexp, $string, $matches);
    return $matches;
}


var_dump(parseliquid("## Hello {%github isn't/safe {%github repo/user %} %}"));
```

Now the expected output is

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(41) "{%github isn't/safe {%github repo/user %}"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "repo/user"
}
```

but the output that comes is

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(41) "{%github isn't/safe {%github repo/user %}"
  [1]=>
  string(30) "isn't/safe {%github repo/user "
}
```

Now what have I done wrong?

Comment: *"Now what have I done wrong?"* choosing regular expression to parse nested expressions (they aren't suited for that, see the regex HTML or JSON parsing problems). You need to either write a proper parser or use an existing one

Comment: @Cid so I can use a lib. Can you tell me some of those?

Comment: I'm sure if you type in your favorite search engine *"liquid php parser"*, you'll find lots of packages

Comment: Ok thanks @Cid               .

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
<?php

function getRepositoryNames(string $value): array
{
    \preg_match_all('/\{\%github\s(?<repo>[a-z0-9-_]+\/[a-z0-9-_]+)\s+/', $value, $matched);

    if (!isset($matched['repo'])) {
        return [];
    }

    return \array_map(static fn ($item) => 'https://github.com/'.$item, $matched['repo']);
}

\var_dump(getRepositoryNames('{%github isnt/safe {%github repo/user1-test %}'));
/*
 array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(28) "https://github.com/isnt/safe"
  [1]=>
  string(34) "https://github.com/repo/user1-test"
}
 */
```

Documentation:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php - Use Example #4

Tested Regex you can this https://regexr.com/

Comment: Thank you! and why did you use \ s?

Comment: `\s` it's short from `space`

If you use `\s` regex try find one space ` `
another `\s+` one or more spaces

Comment: @ŕ̷͉ge̸ḓ̶̅i̷t [regex-cheatsheet](https://web.mit.edu/hackl/www/lab/turkshop/slides/regex-cheatsheet.pdf)